# merge 2 LVMs both have data and on same Volume Group without data loss

Tags: lvm

I have 2 lvm partitons on the same volume group and im wondering if i can merge them to one lvm without data loss

the way i know that i have to create a new physical volume and extend the volume group with that new one and then resize the lvm with the new size and in that case i have to lose my data in order to resize

thanks in advance.

Comment: short answer : you can't.

longer:

what are your "data" ? is this a filesystem ? you cannot concatenate filesystem as a rule. Nor can you concatenate logical volumes.

Comment: ok what about if they are in different Volume Groups

Comment: same answer, however if your data are filesystem, you can grow one (if you have room), copy files and directory, and delete the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF**, the logical volumes are on different volume groups and you want to merge them, use the `vgmerge` command:

First, deactivate the volume group that will be merged into another:

```
[root@host ~]# vgchange -a n vg_to_be_merged
```

After that, test if there is no inconsistence that will prevent you from merging:

```
[root@host ~]# vgmerge -t -v dest_vg vg_to_be_merged
```

Now, do the merge for real:

```
[root@host ~]# vgmerge -v dest_vg vg_to_be_merged
    Checking for volume group "dest_vg"
    Checking for volume group "vg_to_be_merged"
    Archiving volume group "vg_to_be_merged" metadata (seqno 2).
    Archiving volume group "dest_vg" metadata (seqno 13).
    Writing out updated volume group
    Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/dest_vg" (seqno 14).
  Volume group "vg_to_be_merged" successfully merged into "dest_vg"
```

**However,** merging LVM volumes will have no magic trick, since they have filesystems on top of them, and a lot of thinkering with data moving and resizing will be needed.

Further Reading:

- [vgmerge(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgmerge) manpages
- Merging volume groups on [RHEL](https://sites.google.com/site/rhelworldexperience/home/rhel-disk-management---tips-and-tricks/mergingvolumegroupsinrhel-vgmerge)

Comment: so in all cases i will have to store the data on another disk and till resizing complete

Comment: In cases where you want to merge 2 lvs, yes. To merge vgs, is just to use the command above. If you want to do both, you will have to use `vgmerge` and after that, move data between lvs making resize and shrink